# Forecast time series with additional feature

Tags: r, forecasting

Let's say I want to predict the number of people going to the hospital. 
I already have historical daily volumes of people going to the hospital, and simple neural nets (MLP) capture this fairly well.

I want to see if I can further improve the performance  by incorporating weather data (e.g. we would expect when weather gets old more people may go to hospital).

The various R packages I am looking at don't seem to allow me to feed a second feature beyond the original time series data.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

There are several method to do Time Series forecasting when you have others variables apart of time variable itself in R. One of the method I know is called dynamic linear model. You can use this method in ‘dynlm’ package.

Answer (score 0):

> and simple neural nets (MLP) capture this fairly well.

Actually MLP don't do too well on time series problems in general. Statistical models like ARIMA or Exponential Smoothing tend to perform better that NNet based methods. There are some cases where LSTM might give a comparable performance to statistical methods, but AFAIK MLP don't do well on forecasting problems.

> The various R packages I am looking at don't seem to allow me to feed a second feature beyond the original time series data.

This is not correct. Many of the R packages for forecasting allow for external regressors beyond the original time series. In auto.arima, tbats, and nnetar for example you can include them by adding an argument xregs to the model.

In BSTS and Prophet you can as well.